# Can @PostConstruct method be executed after initialization of beans dependent on the one with @PostConstruct?

Tags: spring, postconstruct

I have a spring bean with a singleton scope that performs loading of ssl certificates and some other stuff from files in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. After loading, this ssl stuff is saved to local variable.

This bean is injected to other beans that read these configurations.

Is the `@PostConstruct` method executed immedialtely after bean initialization before initialization of dependent beans? If it is not the case, consummers in my code can get `null` instead of loaded certificates.

Comment: I suggest testing it. In theory it should work.

Comment: It works, but I'd like to be sure that it works all times but not 99 from 100 :)

Comment: It should work 100 of the times, unless you change things in such a way it leads to eager init of beans but that is highly unlikely.